# Can a disconnected srs system ground cause a check engine light?

Tags: cel

Honda Civic coupe vti 1999.

I would think no since it is not related to engine and transmission?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the make, model and year of the car

Comment: @GdD sorry, I have edited.

Comment: Best practice for good communications on a site intended to help inform others is to spell out ALL abbreviations When First Used (WFU). But no disconnecting the ground shouldn’t create a cell phone call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, disconecting the srs/airbag module (or its ground) will not turn on the check engine light. It will only turn on the airbag light and disable the airbag system.